# n arguments in c, function returns int but not double

Tags: c, arguments, return-value

This program is about finding the average of n arguments. It works perfectly with int type, but gives 0.0 when using double. Where is the problem???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
double average(int,...);

double average(int n, ...)
{
  double s = 0.0;
  va_list argumenti;

  va_start(argumenti, n);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    s += va_arg(argumenti, double);
  va_end(argumenti);

  return n ? s / n : 0.0;
}

int main()
{
  printf("average(10.0, 20.0) = %.2lf\n", average(2, 10.0, 20.0));
  printf("average(2.0, 3.5, 4.2) = %.2lf\n", average(3, 2.0, 3.5, 4.2));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: For me, it works, and it looks correct to me. Using `lf` instead of `f` for `double` in `printf` is undefined in C89 (but defined in C99 and C11), I remember a question here where this caused a problem.

Comment: You may want to use `return n>0 ? s / n : 0.0;`

Comment: What isn't working? `f` instead of `lf` or the changed conditional as suggested by Force Bru (which doesn't make a difference for the code shown)?

Comment: Your is working, thanks, comment was meant for ForceBru, sorry

Comment: @АлександарСтјепановић: You can use the @-notation to address specific people (they also get notified in this case). Is your problem solved now? I can write an answer in this case (and I would be interested in what OS you're on and what C library you use), or you may want to delete this question (as I said, we had this before, but maybe your question may help someone with a similar problem).

Comment: I compiled using -std=c99, linked, and ran it.  It worked perfectly

Comment: when compiling, enable all warnings,  then fix the warnings.  Note: if not using -std=c99 (or later), then a warning will be issued.  that warning must be fixed or the code will not work.  The result would be an output of 0.0.

Comment: What machine/compiler are you using? In older versions, a return value had to fit in a register (the ax register on X86). A double does not fit in ax.